# Error linking .ibd/.frm file into access

Tags: mysql, ms-access-2007

I have loaded all but one table into access. I am not familiar with `.frm` or `.idb` files. When trying to link the table `tbl_orderdetails` I am getting an error stating that `MIR.ORDER` is not a valid name. Make sure that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long. I am guessing `MIR.ORDER` is a column name but I did not design the table so I am unsure. Is there any way I can open up the `tbl_orderdetails.frm` or tbl_orderdetails.idb to look for the error and try to correct it?

Comment: How do you try to load these data into ms access? Do you use linked tables?

Comment: @Shadow I am linking all the tables so as they are changed by the program that uses the tables, my access will update as well.